# How to force CouchDB to use HTTP:POST on filtred replication

Tags: couchdb, replication

I'm working on the **one database per user** pattern using CouchDB, my main database contains all my data and i want to create multiple sub-database using CouchDB Replication feature with a filter (i'm filtering the bigger database using : DateMin, DateMax, an Array of IDs, some other conditions based on each user)

https://docs.couchdb.org/en/3.2.0/replication/index.html

https://docs.couchdb.org/en/3.2.0/json-structure.html#replication-settings

When i have a small amount of information for filtering, everything works perfectly,
my problem comes when the Array of IDs that i'm using for filtering contains too much element:

To run the filter, CouchDB is calling an HTTP:GET https://docs.couchdb.org/en/3.2.0/api/database/changes.html#db-changes
which is restricted by the number of character see
([What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers/417184#417184))

But CouchDB has the same request but with HTTP:POST https://docs.couchdb.org/en/3.2.0/api/database/changes.html#post--db-_changes

and i want to know how to specify to CouchDB to use the HTTP:POST for filtering

Additionnal informations :

CouchDB v. 3.1.0

My Replicator Doc :

```
{
  "source": "DB_URL_SOURCE.com",
  "target": "DB_URL_TARGET.com,
  "filter": "mydesigndoc/by_date_and_activities",
  "query_params": {
    "weeksMin": 10,
    "weeksMax": 10,
    "clindividu": true,
    "activitesID": "3988814,3989866,3743378,3742882,2595215,1259813,2596111",
    "cl": true
  },
  "continuous": true
}
```

HTTP:GET request :

```
http://localhost:5984/my-bigdatabase/_changes
    ?filter =mydesigndoc%2Fby_date_and_activities
    &activites=
    &weeksMax=
    &weeksMin=
    &feed=continuous
    &style=all_docs
    &since=0
    &timeout=10000
```

Comment: There are some fixes with POST and _changes filtering in version 3.2.0. Could you try it with the latest version?. e.g. https://github.com/apache/couchdb/pull/3373

Comment: Hi Juanjo Rodriguez thanks for the answer
Yep i'll try this and keep you inform about the result

Comment: @JuanjoRodriguez same problem, Tested on v3.2.0, CouchDB still use HTTP:GET **_change** to filter the replication, and if i set a big array as params for filtering the request  and the replication fails

Comment: It seems that filters allways use GET (https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/3.x/src/couch_replicator/src/couch_replicator_api_wrap.erl#L494) but selectors can solve your problem if yo can convert your filter in a mango expression.

Comment: Hi Juanji, yeah we got the same idea and it works perfectly :D

My only problem now is to adapt my code to programmatically create the replication doc with the selector ^^'

Thanks for helping !